# selenium webdriver .click() is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a download process using python and selenium.

The following is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "symbol").send_keys("AARTISURF")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "get").click()
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Download file in csv format").click()
```

The above code is exported from selenium IDE where it works perfectly fine.
But in python as soon as the "get" is clicked, the code stops and does nothing.
I have tried almost all other 'By's like Xpath, Class, CssSelector etc.

Does anyone know why it happens and how to rectify it?
Also, If you have any better ideas to download this data, Please reply.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply disable blink and add a wait.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"symbol"))).send_keys("AARTISURF")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"get"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"Download file in csv format"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: This is working for first few (like 5 times) but after that it stops working.
I mean if you rerun the entire code for few times, it stops working.  But once I restart the PC it works for few times and stops. Does anyone know to how to correct that?

Comment: I think it is due to my PC but let me know if this works in your PC by running it few times. Do not just loop the code. Run the entire code few times.

Comment: Did you try downloading multiple times? If so you'd have to check download complete prior to clicks.

Comment: It happens the first time itself and the problem is not with the last line. It is with the last before one to click the 'get' ID.

Comment: There is no error message. Also, Control+C is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('submitMe').click();")` instead of actually clicking the button on this site. Keep in mind that this is just a workaround your problem.

Comment: I have tried that also. But for some reason it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add explicit wait before your click. Also, your locators may be wrong.
Use `WebDriverWait`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((SelectBy.CSS, ".download-data-link")))
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".download-data-link")
button.click()
```